# Anaconda Navigator vs Anaconda Prompt: How to execute a file

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I understand that when I access a file using Anaconda Navigator through the list of applications belonging to an environment (e.g. Spyder or Jupyter notebook), the files will run according to the packages specified in that environment.(First image)  However, I have also been trying to achieve the same result by using Anaconda prompt, but I do not know how to do that. My conjecture is to use the command "conda activate py2.7" (Image 2) and then I am clueless. Can someone explain how to execute files directly using

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbhXl.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhnES.jpg)

(I don't have enough reputation to post images, but I hope somebody understands what I tried)

Edit: With reference to Shijith's comment, I tried to change the working directory, but it didn't execute the file. (See below) The file is expected to give an output of 10.2 but nothing appears in the command prompt window.

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Liuw.jpg)

[Example file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLFal.jpg)

Comment: go to the folder containing python file and do a `python filename.py` on anaconda prompt